# Using Different IIS Authentication Based on Binding

Tags: .net, iis, windows-authentication

I built a ASP.NET site that'll be hosted on a server in our network that also has another network card making it a publicly accessible server over the internet.

Internally, the application will be requested using "http://surveys/" whereas online, it'll be accessed as "http://surveys.our-domain.com".

I can add these 2 different "domains" as different bindings to the web app in IIS.

Is there a way to have different authentication methods based on which binding they used? I'd like to use anonymous authentication on the public-facing site and Windows authentication on the local site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Configure different sites please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this based on bindings alone.

But you can set up two separate **Web sites** with different bindings that **point at the same folder** on disk. You can then  set different authentication providers on each site/virtual.

Set up one site with only Anonymous authentication enabled and the other one with only Windows Auth and Anonymous disabled.

Then make sure you add the IUSR account to the permissions of the Web folder and any authenticated users/groups you want to allow access for.

While this is possible, it can be finicky and you have to make sure you get the permissions set just right. You need both IUSR and Windows Auth accounts set up right or else it's easy to get no access to the site at all (401.3 errors with no logon prompts). When I was testing this setup out I ended up with just this scenario the first time and I had to remove the Web folder and restore and then reset the permissions.